# pandas - dynamically fill the missing row of group by(create a duplicate row if required based on previous record)

Tags: python, pandas

Need to fill the data accrding to the stage and last stage is the maximum date

Input:

| RecordID | ChangeDate | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17764 | 31-08-2021 | New |
| 17764 | 02-09-2021 | inprogress |
| 17764 | 05-09-2021 | won |
| 70382 | 04-01-2022 | new |
| 70382 | 06-01-2022 | hold |
| 70382 | 07-01-2022 | lost |

Expceted output:

| RecordID | ChangeDate | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17764 | 31-08-2021 | New |
| 17764 | 01-09-2021 | New |
| 17764 | 02-09-2021 | inprogress |
| 17764 | 03-09-2021 | inprogress |
| 17764 | 04-09-2021 | inprogress |
| 17764 | 05-09-2021 | won |
| 70382 | 04-01-2022 | new |
| 70382 | 05-01-2022 | new |
| 70382 | 06-01-2022 | hold |
| 70382 | 07-01-2022 | lost |

Comment: please provide your datasets as **text**

Comment: it's just example, You can create sample dataset

Comment: Well, **you** should do the work of providing us with a reproducible example ;)

Comment: updated now @mozway

Comment: I imagine the increment in ID was a typo

Comment: yes, it's typo.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), to expose missing rows:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build a list of new dates
new_dates = {'ChangeDate': lambda df: pd.date_range(df.min(), df.max(), freq='1D')}

df.complete(new_dates, by = 'RecordID').ffill()
Out[70]: 
   RecordID ChangeDate       Stage
0     17764 2021-08-31         New
1     17764 2021-09-01         New
2     17764 2021-09-02  inprogress
3     17764 2021-09-03  inprogress
4     17764 2021-09-04  inprogress
5     17764 2021-09-05         won
6     70382 2022-01-04         new
7     70382 2022-01-05         new
8     70382 2022-01-06        hold
9     70382 2022-01-07        lost
```

Another option is to build a dataframe, and do a merge with the original dataframe - this is useful for non-unique values:

```py
index = (df
.set_index('ChangeDate')
.drop(columns='Stage')
.groupby('RecordID')
.apply(lambda df: df.asfreq(freq='1D'))
.index)
new_df = pd.DataFrame([], index = index)
(new_df
.merge(df, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_on = ['RecordID', 'ChangeDate'])
.ffill())

   RecordID ChangeDate       Stage
0     17764 2021-08-31         New
5     17764 2021-09-01         New
1     17764 2021-09-02  inprogress
5     17764 2021-09-03  inprogress
5     17764 2021-09-04  inprogress
2     17764 2021-09-05         won
3     70382 2022-01-04         new
5     70382 2022-01-05         new
4     70382 2022-01-06        hold
5     70382 2022-01-07        lost
```

Comment: it's not creating records after multiple stages

Comment: which is failing the `complete` solution or the outer merge option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`groupby.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
df['ChangeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ChangeDate'], dayfirst=True)

(df.set_index('ChangeDate')
   .groupby('RecordID', as_index=False)
   .resample('1d').ffill()
   .reset_index('ChangeDate')
)
```

Output:

```
  ChangeDate  RecordID       Stage
0 2021-08-31     17764         New
0 2021-09-01     17764         New
0 2021-09-02     17764  inprogress
0 2021-09-03     17764  inprogress
0 2021-09-04     17764  inprogress
0 2021-09-05     17764         won
1 2022-01-04     70382         new
1 2022-01-05     70382         new
1 2022-01-06     70382        hold
1 2022-01-07     70382        lost
```

Comment: error:
    "cannot reindex a non-unique index "
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit 

And Can't understand the above comment:
I imagine the increment in ID was a typo

Comment: This means you have duplicated dates per ID, how do you want to handle those? The comment was for my [modification of you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74458068/revisions)

Comment: Yeah, Combination of recordID, ChangeDate,Stage only unique

Comment: For non unique a merge could help

Comment: Can you provide the code @sammywemmy?

Comment: Facing this error: @mozway
 "cannot reindex a non-unique index "
ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit